# Mips architecture addresses calculated by the ALU

Tags: architecture, mips

In a mips architecture because the instructions `lw` and `sw` need to go through the ALU to calculate the address? This address is the registers sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the address that needs to go into the ALU is in the source register, `RS`.

`LW` and `SW` have the format below:

```
LW rt, offset(rs)
SW rt, offset(rs)
```

So you need to add the offset and the `rs` to get the address for memory access.

And just FYI, `rt` means the target register above.

Hope this helps!